# How can i insert html code in a html file in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to insert the cihantoker tag if there are no orders but it doesn't work.

I want to insert the h1 tag into a html file so res.send() does not work because it inserts the h1 tag on a empty website.I tried to make it with data_8+cihantoker
(data_8 is a variable for the html file) but it didn't work.How can I do this ?

```
 var order_count=order_count_result[0];


//TODO:If there is no orders


                                                                                if(order_count==0){

                                                                                        data_8=data_7.replace("#no-ordered-food-div{display: none;}","no-ordered-food-div{display:inline-block;}");

                                                                                        res.write(data_8+"<h1 id='cihantoker-text'>cihantoker</h1>");

res.end();

}
```

Comment: learn [res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) and use a templating lib, then do that logic in the template/view

Comment: btw if `order_count_result[0]` is `undefined`, `if(order_count==0){` will be false, then guessing the else in your code is if there is orders

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no it is not undefined.Normally no-ordered-food-div's display is none;But when i define the order_count=0;i can see the div.

Answer (score 0):

if + is not working chances are data8 is an object not a string.

try:

```
    let h1 = "<h1 id='cihantoker-text'>cihantoker</h1>";
    let result = data8.concat(h1);
                                                                                        
    res.write(result);
    res.end();
}
```

see if it throws an error like concat is not a method